TypeError: Cannot read property 'RNFSFileTypeRegular' of null, js engine: hermes
These are my dependencies from package.json
 "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "expo": "~51.0.23",
    "expo-constants": "~16.0.2",
    "expo-font": "~12.0.9",
    "expo-linking": "~6.3.1",
    "expo-router": "~3.5.19",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.27.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "expo-system-ui": "~3.0.7",
    "expo-web-browser": "~13.0.3",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.3",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.16.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-reanimated-carousel": "^3.5.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.5",
    "react-native-screens": "3.31.1",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.10"
  },

And I'm using Expo bundlier.
This is my GettingStarted.jsx
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs'
import Carousel from 'react-native-reanimated-carousel'

export default function GettingStarted() {
  const [file, setFile] = useState([]);
  const dir = `${RNFS.PicturesDirectoryPath}social/assets/Img`
  const imgUrl = async () => {
    try {
      const exist = await RNFS.exists(dir)
      if (exist) {
        console.log("Directory Exist", dir);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error reading subdirectory:', error);
    }
  }
  imgUrl()
  return (
    <View>
      <Carousel >

      </Carousel>
    </View>
  )
}

Index.tsx
import { Text, View } from "react-native";
import GettingStarted from '@/app/(auth)/gettingStarted'

export default function Index() {
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
      }}
    >
      <GettingStarted></GettingStarted>
    </View>
  );
}


try manual linking using react-native link react-native-fs

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I got it fixed . Actually the expo bindler does not support react-native-fs library
